# Styling card with different styles which were created using ngFor in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

So what I'm trying to do is to apply different styles to cards which were created using ngFor in Angular.

For now it's looking like this: 
[image: Current look]

My goal is to set different styles for each card. Since it was created with ngFor loop I could only change a style for all of them.

Then I managed to assign a class for each card element:

```
<div *ngFor="let module of modules" class="{{module.name}}">
```

After that I applied style in CSS:

```
div.Rekrutacja {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
}
```

which partially worked. It selected first element, but I can't really modify it. I set background color to black and that what I got:

[image]

So it just applied to some area (I have no idea what area it is), and I can't get inside actual mat-card to change it apart from the rest.

HTML:

```
    <div class="flex-container">
  <div *ngFor="let module of modules" class="{{module.name}}">
    <mat-card matRipple [matRippleColor]="white"  class="flex-items hvr-reveal" *ngxPermissionsOnly="module.permissionsRequired">
      <span routerLink={{module.routing}}>
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            <h1>
              <p style="text-align: center;">
                {{module.name}}
              </p>
            </h1>
          </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <div class="mat-icon-card">
          <p style="text-align: center">
          <mat-icon>{{module.icon}}</mat-icon>
          </p>
        </div>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <mat-card-content>
          <h3>
            <p style="text-align: center">
              {{module.description}}
            </p>
          </h3>
        </mat-card-content>
      </span>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mat-card {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

div.Rekrutacja {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
}
```

TS:

```
modules: any = [
    {
      name: 'Rekrutacja',
      icon: 'group',
      description: 'Moduł obsługi działu rekrutacji. Zarządzanie kandydatami.',
      routing: '/recruitment',
      permissionsRequired: [CONSTS.permissionCodes.accessRecruitmentModule]
    },
    {
      name: 'Sprzedaż',
      icon: 'work',
      description: 'Moduł obsługi działu sprzedaży. Zarządzenie firmami, osobami kontaktowymi i leadami.',
      routing: '/sales',
      permissionsRequired: [CONSTS.permissionCodes.accessSalesModule]
    },
    {
      name: 'Ustawienia',
      icon: 'settings',
      description: 'Moduł panelu administracyjnego. Zarządzanie użytkownikami i ustawieniami aplikacji.',
      routing: '/admin-panel',
      permissionsRequired: [CONSTS.permissionCodes.accessAdminPanelModule]
    },
  ];
```

Comment: is there a logic according to which you need to style these? is it that EACH card has a different style and NO associated logic based ion which that style is applied?

Comment: Previously I just needed all three card to have white background. Now I need to apply different bg colors for each card. It sounded pretty simple, but turn out I can't really style only one element.

Comment: Did you try to write in your css `::ng-deep div.Rekrutacja .mat-card { background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1) !important; }`? This should bypass styles encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of targeting the `<div>` that wraps the `<mat-card>` which will cause the background color to be applied to `<div>`, target the actual `<mat-card>` of the respective `<div>`:

```
div.Rekrutacja .mat-card {
  background-color: rgb(1, 1, 1);
}

div.Sprzedaż .mat-card {
  background-color: blue;
}

div.Ustawienia .mat-card {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Here is a simplified [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-puu8s3) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Dude, works like a magic! 
I actually did it, but I wrote div.Rekrutacja.mat-card together, that why it didn't work!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain me what is the difference between .div.Rekrutacja and .div .Rekrutacja?

Comment: @Lbovsky If you have a space character between `div` and `.Rekrutacja`, that would be trying to target **any** element with class `Rekrutacja` on a **child** (Descendant) of `div`.  Without the space, `div.Rekrutacja` finds a `<div>` element that has class `Rekrutacja`. I'd argue that `div.Rekrutacja` has better performance than `div Rekrutacja`.